# MediaElement with embebed play/pause controls?

Tags: video, windows-8, mpmovieplayercontroller

Microsoft shows an example [of playing MediaElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx) but defined a set of controls with a layout. Is there any way (or controller) that has embebed video controlers? (pause/play/ advance to a certain point in time)

I am looking for the MPMoviePlayer for iOS but for Windows (and [I didn't find it in this API mapping resource provided by Microsoft](http://apimappingsite.cloudapp.net/library?source=iOS#iOS-iOS-MediaPlayer_framework)). Is there any?

Comment: As an aside, for performance purposes, we are now counseling developers to NOT put controls over a MediaElement. Put them to the side. You CAN, it's just a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Player Framework:

- http://playerframework.codeplex.com/
- http://programmerpayback.com/2012/06/01/microsoft-media-platform-player-framework-for-windows-8-release-preview/